# How to update composer in windows?

Tags: composer-php

When I tried to update composer using "composer self-update" command in windows 10, An error is occurring[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixBG3.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the command line, use the Windows installer found here: https://getcomposer.org/download/.